# Is it possible to load parent-child tables with SQL Loader

Tags: oracle12c, sql-loader

I need to load data into a parent-child pair of tables with SQL Loader.
For various reasons the customer prefers to extract the data into one consolidated file, hence I'll have a data file containing main records (*ID, First Name and Last Name*) and then several phone numbers for each main record (*ID, phone type, phone*).

```
1, John, Doe
2, Mary, Doe
3, Sandy, Smith
1, home, 88899999
1, mobile, 7777777
2, home 6666666
3, office,3333333
3, mobile, 7777777
```

My goal is to load two tables: **emp** - with main record data and **emp_phones** with child records.
Is it possible to implement this with SQL Loader?
I can request from them to put some record "type" identifier in front of the line, like 'main', or 'phone' if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that some sort of type indicator not just helps, but is required. SQL Loader has a "when" clause that will allow you to decide which table to load your records into.